# Why there is a quick white flicker when switching between different Tkinter Canvases with an image as background?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas

I know this question or similar questions are asked multiple time here, But I am unable to get the proper answer. Please don't delete my question.

I am trying to make a game using tkinter GUI. My aim is to make different Canvas, with same or different images as a background, for different menus/screens.
But I have noticed that when I switch between different menus (canvases), there is a quick white flash during the switching which is undesirable. As far as I know, this is because when I "pack_forget" the previous canvas and pack the new one, the is a small difference between the two events
But I want the switching to be smooth because such a flickering doesn't look good in a game.
I have attached a code below. The code is a bit long. Actually I tried to reduce it as much as I could. So the code below is the minimum required code to check the problem.

This is what you should do:

1. Run the program and click "New Game".
2. Then click the 'Back' arrow shown at the bottom of the window.
3. If you are unable to notice the flickering (or you may say "A quick white flash"), then keep repeating step 1 and 2.

The Image for the canvas background is attached here:
[Image for Canvas background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfha2.png)

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class DiceGame(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DiceGame, self).__init__()

        self.title("Dice Cricket")
        self.geometry('980x660+200-60')
        self.state('zoomed')

        self.font1 = ('Algerian', 95, 'bold')
        self.font2 = ('Comic Sans MS', 50, 'bold')
        self.font3 = ('Comic Sans MS', 40, 'bold')
        self.font4 = ('Comic Sans MS', 30, 'bold')
        self.font5 = ('Comic Sans MS', 25, 'bold')
        self.bgcolor = '#366649'

        self.background1 = PhotoImage(file = 'dicepic9.png')
        self.back_image = PhotoImage(file = "back arrow.png").subsample(7,7)
        self.MainMenu()
        self.Actice_Window = "MainMenu"

    def gameTitle(self, root):
        title_Label = Label(root,
                        text = "Dice Cricket",
                        font = self.font1,
                        bg = self.bgcolor,
                        fg = 'yellow')
        title_Label.grid(row = 0, column = 1, pady = 15, ipadx = 100)

    def backbutton(self, root):
        self.back_Label = Label(root,
                            text = "Back",
                            font = self.font5,
                            fg = "Yellow",
                            bg = self.bgcolor,
                            image = self.back_image,
                            compound = LEFT)

        return self.back_Label

    def MainMenu(self):
        self.MainMenu_Canvas = Canvas(self, bg = self.bgcolor, highlightthickness = 0)
        self.MainMenu_Canvas.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)
        self.MainMenu_Canvas.create_image(2, 2, anchor = NW, image = self.background1)
    
        self.gameTitle(self.MainMenu_Canvas)

        self.MainMenu_Frame = Frame(self.MainMenu_Canvas)
        self.MainMenu_Frame.grid(row = 1, column = 1, pady = 10, ipadx = 20)

        self.MainMenu_Label = Label(self.MainMenu_Frame,
                        text = "Main Menu",
                        font = self.font2,
                        bg = self.bgcolor,
                        fg = 'orange')
        self.MainMenu_Label.pack(fill = X, pady = (0,0))

        self.Options_Frame = Frame(self.MainMenu_Frame, bg = 'gray10', bd = 4, relief = GROOVE)
        self.Options_Frame.pack(fill = X, ipady = 5, ipadx = 60)

        label1 = Label(self.Options_Frame, text = "New Game", font = self.font4, bg = "gray10", fg = "light green")
        label1.pack()
        label1.bind('<Button-1>', self.NewGame_Menu)

    def NewGame_Menu(self, event):
        self.Actice_Window = "NewGame Menu"
        self.MainMenu_Canvas.pack_forget()

        self.NewGameMenu_Canvas = Canvas(self, bg = self.bgcolor, highlightthickness = 0)
        self.NewGameMenu_Canvas.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)
        self.NewGameMenu_Canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor = NW, image = self.background1)

        self.gameTitle(self.NewGameMenu_Canvas)

        self.NewGame_Frame = Frame(self.NewGameMenu_Canvas, bg = self.bgcolor)
        self.NewGame_Frame.grid(row = 1, column = 1, pady = 10)

        self.selection_Label = Label(self.NewGame_Frame, text = "Select Game Type", font = self.font3, fg = "Silver", bg = self.bgcolor)
        self.selection_Label.pack()

        self.Matchtype_Frame = Frame(self.NewGame_Frame, bg = 'gray10', bd = 4, relief = GROOVE)
        self.Matchtype_Frame.pack(ipadx = 60, ipady = 10, pady = 15)

        label2 = Label(self.Matchtype_Frame, text = "Quick Match", font = self.font4, bg = "gray10", fg = "light green")
        label2.pack()
    
        self.back1 = self.backbutton(self.NewGameMenu_Canvas)
        self.back1.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W, padx = 190, pady = 10)
        self.back1.bind('<Button-1>', self.Go_Back)

    def Go_Back(self, event):
        if self.Actice_Window == "NewGame Menu":
           self.NewGameMenu_Canvas.pack_forget()
           self.MainMenu_Canvas.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)

dice = DiceGame()
dice.mainloop()
```

Comment: A [mcve] would help pinpoint the issue.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I have minimized my code. Now check it again please.

Comment: I can tell in one second of looking at your code that you didn't minimize it, because there are five different font styles, and that surely isn't the only thing that could be eliminated.